# Can I put vote in salesforce knowledge article's list view

Tags: lightning-knowledge

We have enabled vote in our salesforce lightning knowledge. I have realised those vote numbers are actually on an object called vote so I can't directly add that field into knowledge's list view.

I am thinking of ways like formula fields or trigger. But it seems to me that I can't create a formula field based on votes or create a trigger on vote object. So how can I achieve this?